# Roots of $|x|^{\tan(x)}-x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, roots

For $f(x)=|x|^{\tan(x)}-x$, I am curious about the relation between the roots of $f(x)$. On plotting it in Desmos, I got the roots as $\frac{\pi}{4}$, 1, $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, $\frac{9\pi}{4}$, $\frac{13\pi}{4}$, $\frac{17\pi}{4}$, and so on. But I'm not able to establish a relation between them like the $k^{th}$ root is equal to $\frac{f(k)\pi}{4}$. I tried to simplify, $$f(x)=|x|^{\tan(x)}-x=0$$ $$|x|^{\tan(x)}=x$$ $$\log_x(|x|^{\tan(x)})=1$$ $$\tan(x)=1$$ That is fine till here. But then why are the roots not at $\frac{n\pi}{4}$?

Comment: $tan(x)=1$ when $x= \pi / 4 + n\pi$. The solution $x=1$ is separate: at that point you can’t take $\log_x$.

Comment: $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi $ cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT.** What are the roots of $\tan(x)$? Check your solution. (Really $\dfrac{n\pi}{4}$?)

Meanwhile, we can't take $\log_x$ when $x=1$. The case of $x=1$ should be separated to consider.